# Why doesn't this menu toggle?

Tags: javascript

On my site (http://test.tamarawobben.nl) I use an accordion menu. When I choose the 2005 option and after that 2006, 2005 stays open though I was expecting it would close.

Can anyone give me a hint why this happens and how to fix it?

Roelof

Comment: What sort of code are you using to collapse the menu?

Comment: Posting the relevant snippet of code would help so we don't have to dig through your site.

Comment: post some code; this isn't wizard school ;)

Comment: If you link to your site, and then *fix* it on your site, then this question loses *all* context.  Please update the question with the relevant pieces of code so the problem is adequately explained *here*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup seems to be wrong for this kind of plugin you are using.

Your markup looks like this, with several menu items for each menu:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">2005</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li>Subitem</li>
    ....
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li>Subitem</li>
    ....
  </ul>
</ul>
```

How i see it, the `ul`-element with class "menu" has to work as a wrapper, so there should only be one "menu" element, that has all the lists in it. Otherwise it won't work as an accordion. Try something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">2005</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem</li>
      ....
    </ul>

    <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem</li>
      ....
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle of my implementation of what your trying to achieve. As you didn't provide your code, I guessed the HTML and wrote some jQuery.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/6E2xJ/1/

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

My first observation is that you need to add 'collapsible' to the class names for each menu, i.e:

```
<ul class="menu collapsible" id="menu2005">
```

and

```
<ul class="menu collapsible" id="menu2006">
```

(Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/zN6d9/)

I know JavaScript, HTML and CSS, but not jQuery >.< but I'll have a fiddle and update if I get anywhere!

Edit:

OK, so after spending ages on jsfiddle, I realised I SUPIDLY forgot to remove the reference to menu.js from the HTML section, hence my modifications in the JavaScript section were ignored :(

Anywho, I gave myself a crash course in staring at jQuery and got reasonably familiar with it!  I was sure I isolated the problem, although I made that stupid mistake as I mention above.

Now, to the point, I made a tiny alteration to the JavaScript and BAM:
http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/zN6d9/1/

Update your menu.js to look like the JavaScript section and remember those class names I mentioned above! :)